# How to play online stream in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I  have online radio (shout cast ) in web. I want to develop android app for listen this stream. so I want to know how to play online stream in android. using URL. **In Android Im not going to Stream the audio**. I want listen the web stream from android app.
How to do that..?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
private void init() throws IOException {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        String streamPath = "";//enter path
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamPath);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong url for mediaplayer! " + ex);
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong url for mediaplayer! " + ex);
    }
}

private void play() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link it may help you a while, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html